# Count mysql rows by hourly for given date

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, count

I have a mysql table with date column. date column data type is TIMESTAMP and default set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP which record both date and time

now i want to count my rows under given day

As an example

```
 ++++++++++ 8am 9am 10am 11am
 ++user1+++  15  10  11    10
 ++user2+++  10  10  20    30
```

Every hour count should be recorded separately like this.

i tried with this but it's not working

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable 
WHERE `date` = '2015-01-26' 
GROUP BY HOUR(`TIMESTAMP`)
```

how can i achieve this ?

i have no idea how to group with user . sproc is also okay

I made a sproc like this. but this sproc contain errors. can some one please help me now i want to count this separated by 9 hours

```
  DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test22`(IN datestamp DATE)
BEGIN
SELECT username, 

       COUNT(if(disblid,1,null)) '8:00 AM', where time between '08:00' and '09:00':
        COUNT(if(disblid,1,null)) '9:00 AM' , where time between '09:00' and '10:00';




FROM claimloans 
WHERE DATE(date) = datestamp
group by Username;

   END
```

Thanks for everyone who helped me I come up with sproc that working perfectly fine.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `claimscounter`(IN datestamp DATE)
BEGIN
SELECT username, 

    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=0,1,NULL)) AS '12am',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=1,1,NULL)) AS '1am',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=2,1,NULL)) AS '2am',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=3,1,NULL)) AS '3am',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=4,1,NULL)) AS '4am',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=5,1,NULL)) AS '5am',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=6,1,NULL)) AS '6am',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=7,1,NULL)) AS '7am',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=8,1,NULL)) AS '8am',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=9,1,NULL)) AS '9am',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=10,1,NULL)) AS '10am',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=11,1,NULL)) AS '11am',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=12,1,NULL)) AS '12pm',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=13,1,NULL)) AS '1pm',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=14,1,NULL)) AS '2pm',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=15,1,NULL)) AS '3pm',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=16,1,NULL)) AS '4pm',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=17,1,NULL)) AS '5pm',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=18,1,NULL)) AS '6pm',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=19,1,NULL)) AS '7pm',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=20,1,NULL)) AS '8pm',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=21,1,NULL)) AS '9pm',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=22,1,NULL)) AS '10pm',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(date)=23,1,NULL)) AS '11pm'


FROM claimloans 
WHERE DATE(date) = datestamp
group by username;

   END
```

But now I have another small problem. This count all the hours. if it's not entry for some hour it count as zero. I want to count hours only have records  can someone help me with this

thnaks

Comment: that's a pivot query, and mysql doesn't support them. do the pivoting in your client code and save yourself a lot of hairpulling.

Comment: sir can you please tell me more about this. I only have little knowledge in SQl

Comment: sir i wrotea sproc can you please look in to it ??

Comment: You could write 24 `COUNT(IF(HOUR(date) = 12,1,0)), ...` clauses in your select then group by username. But that could get awkward quickly

Comment: what that means ? could you please show me correct way to do it please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve this as a view, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id int not null, val timestamp);

CREATE VIEW foo_by_hours AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        DATE(val) AS 'day',
        COUNT(IF(HOUR(val)=0,1,NULL)) AS '12am',
        COUNT(IF(HOUR(val)=1,1,NULL)) AS '1am',
        COUNT(IF(HOUR(val)=2,1,NULL)) AS '2am',
        COUNT(IF(HOUR(val)=3,1,NULL)) AS '3am',
        ...
    FROM foo
    GROUP BY id, day);

SELECT * FROM foo_by_hours;
```

Full example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9fa8ed/1/0)
I also added a view which uses `SUM` instead of `COUNT`. The result is the same, it's just a different way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you very much sir this worked, but this shows only one user data why is that ? and could you pleas tell me the how can I filter this only today records not from all the table data ?

Comment: and this enter view data to my current table I want to display it from datagrid view

Comment: Thanks sir I made a sproc using your view and now its working. and again I update my question little bit could you please look in to it